# How Do I Migrate From HTTPS to HTTP?

Tags: .htaccess, https

I am redesigning a website that is currently served over `HTTPS` via WPEngine. The new site will just be a static HTML landing page, which will be hosted on a totally new server over `HTTP`.

My concern is that users will get [connection errors](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869?hl=en). Can I just use `.htaccess` to redirect `HTTPS` to `HTTP` to solve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect HTTPS to HTTP in .htaccess for specific domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178819/how-can-i-redirect-https-to-http-in-htaccess-for-specific-domains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this could help you, in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect https://www.test.com to http://www.test.com

For more http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-htaccess-redirect-https-http

Comment: Since there is a legitimate SSL certificate associated with the domain on one server, I won't run into any issues when there is no certificate installed in the new server (even with the HTTP redirect), correct? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes.Correct. Just one note I have mentioned `301` in `RewriteRule` which is about Permanent Redirect, you can use `302` for temporary redirect as per your requirement.